# Remove extra headers from email

Tags: python, header, smtp

I'm trying to create a good email bulk sender. I've written this function:

```
def send(server_ip,username,password,recipient,count):
    sender = 'prova <' + username +'>'
    body = ''.join(tempMail)
    body = body.replace('#email#', recipient)
    body = body.replace('#random#', rand_string())
    subject = "Test smpt sender"
    headers = ["From: " + sender, "Subject: " + subject, "To: " + recipient, "MIME-Version: 1.0", "Content-Type: text/html"]
    headers = "\r\n".join(headers)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(server_ip)  
        server.login(username,password)
        server.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\n\n" + body)
        code = server.ehlo()[0]
        server.quit()
        print "[+] Send to",recipient + " smpt :",server_ip
    except:
        listSMPT.pop(count)
        print "[-] Error send to " + recipient + '\t' + server_ip
```

But I have one problem: All emails I send have my IP address in email headers.
I need a solution without use of sockets or proxy!
Is it possible to send emails without this data in email headers?
If I have IP of SMTP in headers, it's not problem, I need to remove only IP to PC where python is working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a remote SMTP server to relay your email. E.g., you submit your email to another server and the server sends the email for you.

In this case, the IP address of your machine where the Python script runs you see in `Received:` header is added by that very first relay server your Python script connects to.

If you can control that first-hop relay (for example it's a Postfix server you run), you could do some tricks on the server to remove / censor that header.